# XSL-FO image path problems - changing backslashes to forward

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have the following abc.xml snippet.

`<abc>Images\Image.JPG</abc>`

and I want to display this image on a PDF.  I am using Apache FOP to translate my XML to PDF using XSL-FO. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out a clever way to replace the backslashes as forward slashes.  Here is some xsl code I'm playing with:

`<fo:external-graphic>
    <xsl:variable name="fixTest">file:///<xsl:value-of select="abc"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="src" select="'{translate(@fixTest, '\','/')}'"/>
</fo:external-graphic>`

I also have some code that I've been trying to be to no avail.  Now I know once I figure out how to replace '\' with '/' with the XSL-FO file, I will be able to display my image.  However right now I cannot figure out how to do that.

`<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="concat('file:///',translate(@abc, '\', '/'))"/></xsl:attribute>`

Does anyone have any idea how I can translate '\' into '/' in my text value of element `abc` so I can also concatenate `file:///` onto that value and set it as my `src` attribute for `fo:external-graphic`?

Comment: In your snippet, `abc` is an *element*, not an *attribute* - so `@abc` does not select it. Nor does `@fixTest` select a *variable*. Hard to say more without seeing the context.

Comment: I want my `src` attribute of `external-graphic` to be set to `file:///PATH/TO/IMG.jpg`.  `src` path needs to include `file:///` so it must be concatenated with the `abc` element value (image path).  I can get the image path with `<xsl:value of select="abc">` but the slashes are backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bit too long to write in comments, but in your question you show you are doing this...

```
<xsl:attribute name="src" select="'{translate(@fixTest, '\','/')}'"/>
```

(Although, as you went on to show, it should really be `.` here, not `@fixTest`)

But, this means you have apostrophes nested in a string delimited by apostrophes, which is a syntax error. So, you should have written this to make it syntactically correctly.

```
<xsl:attribute name="src" select="'{translate(@fixTest, &quot;\&quot;,&quot;/&quot;)}'"/>
```

But this would have shown you what the problem was. `select` expects an expression. By using delimiting the expression with apostrophes, you have turned it into a string literal, so the expression does not get evaluated. But you didn't need to use apostrophes or curly braces here. You should have written this....

```
<xsl:attribute name="src" select="translate(., '\', '\')"/>
```

Or, to add the "file:///" prefix....

```
<xsl:attribute name="src" select="concat('file:///',translate(., '\', '/'))"/>
```

But there is an even easy way, one where the curly braces (also known as Attribute Value Templates) do apply, and that is to write this...

```
<fo:external-graphic src="file:///{translate(., '\', '/')}">
```

Here, the `src` attribute does expect a string, and the curly braces are then used to evaluate an expression instead.

Comment: This is the kind of explanation I was looking for - thank you Tim C!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out my own issue.  I did not include my `<xsl:template match="abc">` element because I did not think it was important to my issue.  So what I needed to do was use `.` to reference my own template value while setting the `src` attribute here

`<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="concat('file:///',translate(., '\', '/'))"/></xsl:attribute>`

The whole snippet of my xsl code is below.

`<xsl:template match="abc">
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="abc">
            <fo:external-graphic>
                <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="concat('file:///',translate(., '\', '/'))"/></xsl:attribute>
            </fo:external-graphic>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>`